# Convert NSData back to NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uitextview

I have managed to save the NSAttributedString as a PFFile to Parse.

Now I am trying to download that PFFile, and convert it back into a NSAttrbutedString....

The NSAttributedString, comes from my UITextView which has obviously some text and then several images.

This is how I save it :

```
let data: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(recievedUploadText)
post["textPost"] = PFFile(name:"text.txt", data:data)
```

I just convert it to NSData and then save it normally.

Any ideas how I could download it correctly so, the images and everything else displays correctly?

This is my downloading code so far:

```
        post.text!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

                do {

                cell.Text.attributedText = try NSAttributedString(data: data!, options: [:], documentAttributes: nil)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }}
```

Any questions on my code, just drop a comment below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject` to archive the data, you must use the symmetrical API `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData` to unarchive it, rather than the NSAttributedString `init(data:options:...)`.

Comment: Ah ok, and how would I implement the NSKeyedUnarchiver? inside of the getDataInBackground?

Comment: Figured it out, Thanks a lot!